# Default (dummy) backend for Azure application gateway

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have an application gateway that needs to combine a couple of functionapps and some blob storages to a single domain. So I route the specific paths to the appropriate resources. But then the URL path map still wants a default backend. Well, but I don't really have one. I just want the app gateway to return 404 for anything that didn't match any path.

Is there some backend setting that I could use that would just return 404 for any path without having to create an empty storage account or similar dummy resource?

When using it as Kubernetes ingress controller it works like that, i.e. anything that does not match any Ingress record simply gets 404, but this app gateway is in front of plain Azure resources, not AKS.